# Kill explorer.exe with windows title

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I'm new with programing and my question is now, how i can close some specific explorer.exe windows. My Problem is, i have a program that call some windows:

```
Option Explicit

Dim shell, expl1, expl2, expl3, Terminate

Dim uprgExplorer

  set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  set expl1 = shell.exec("C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe c:\Documents and Settings")
  set expl2 = shell.exec("C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe C:\WINDOWS\system32\CCM\Cache")
  set expl3 = shell.exec("C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe c:\SCRIPTS\LOG")
```

Now i will kill only this 3 windows NOT the explorer.exe.

Can some one help me?

Greetings,

matthias

Comment: I mean, can you code the solution in a C# DLL, then call the functionality from vb script?

Comment: I can't C#, i only can a little bit wsh/vb.

Can you help me? Thank you very mutch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `SendKeys` function to close the Explorer windows:

```
set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

set expl1 = shell.exec("C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe c:\tmp")

MsgBox "Explorer started."

success = shell.appactivate("c:\tmp")
if success then shell.sendkeys "%{F4}"
```

You might also want to have a look at [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), which allows you to record macros and [manipulate windows](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#Activate).